# Cauchy problem for the Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Let $(M, g_{\mu\nu})$ be a globally hyperbolic spacetime and let $\Sigma$ be a spacelike Cauchy surface. The covariant Klein-Gordon equation has a well-posed initial value formulation, in the following sense: given any pair of smooth, compactly supported initial condition on $\Sigma$, $(\phi_{0}, \dot\phi_{0})$, there exists a unique solution, $\phi$, defined on all $M$, such that $(\phi|_{\Sigma},n_\Sigma \cdot\nabla \phi|_\Sigma)=(\phi_{0},\dot\phi_{0})$.

I have some questions:

1. Is it true both for real and complex solutions?
2. Going in the other direction, is it true that, given a smooth solution on all $M$, this solution must have compact support on $\Sigma$?
3. How about the plane wave $e^{ikx}$ in flat spacetime? Is this a solution that doesn't fit into this set?

Comment: You've answered your own question for #2 by giving your example in #3.  This shows that non-compact initial data on $\Sigma$ can sometimes be extended to a solution on $M$.  I expect that one can contrive some interesting counterexamples where existence and/or uniqueness fail, but they aren't coming to mind just now.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, by linearity
2. of course, not. Solutions with start values on a compact set of a Cauchy surface decompose into retarded and advanced soultions, confined to the inner of the image of the forward and backward light cones of the compact set.
3. plane waves are distributional solutions, but they can be used with a smooth Gaussian cutoff at spatial infinity to be elements of the Hilbert space.  But their main purpose is to simplify the algebra of states and observables by  Fourier transform.

Comment: Plane waves are not distributional solutions. They are perfectly fine functions. They are not elements of $L^2$, and therefore their Fourier transform is not a function and only exists in a distributional sense.

Comment: Your answer for 2, doesn’t address the asked question.

Comment: @TimRias: Indeed, the largest class of sensible solutions turns out to be such that Fourier and inverse Fourier transforms after application of the operator exists. Can be roughly described as $$\mathit L^1\text{(all 3d-Cauchy hypersurfaces})$$